# "Fair-use" and "copyright" tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We have four questions using the [fair-use](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fair-use) tag, and all of them are questions about fair use of a copyrighted work.

All [fair-use](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fair-use) questions are, by definition, going to be [copyright](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) questions. Is there any objection to setting the [fair-use](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fair-use) tag as a synonym to the [copyright](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) tag?

Comment: Sounds like a good synonym to me. :)

Comment: Sounds good to me too.

Comment: Done, it just needs approval. http://writers.stackexchange.com/tags/fair-use/synonyms